# CRC16 CCITT Java implementation

Tags: java, c, crc16

There is a function written in C that calculates CRC16 CCITT. It helps reading data from RFID reader - and basically works fine. I would like to write a function in Java that would do similar thing.
I tried online converter page to do this, but the code I got is garbage.
Could you please take a look at this and advice why Java code that should do the same generates different crc?
Please find attached original C function:

```
void CRC16(unsigned char * Data, unsigned short * CRC, unsigned char Bytes)
{
    int i, byte;
    unsigned short C;

    *CRC = 0;
    for (byte = 1; byte <= Bytes; byte++, Data++)
    {
        C = ((*CRC >> 8) ^ *Data) << 8;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (C & 0x8000)
                C = (C << 1) ^ 0x1021;
            else
                C = C << 1;
        }
        *CRC = C ^ (*CRC << 8);
    }
}
```

And here is the different CRC function written in JAVA that should calculate the same checksum, but it does not:

```
public static int CRC16_CCITT_Test(byte[] buffer) {
     int wCRCin = 0x0000; 
     int wCPoly = 0x1021; 
     for (byte b : buffer) {
         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             boolean bit = ((b >> (7 - i) & 1) == 1);
             boolean c15 = ((wCRCin >> 15 & 1) == 1);
             wCRCin <<= 1;
             if (c15 ^ bit)
                 wCRCin ^= wCPoly;
         }
     }
     wCRCin &= 0xffff;
     return wCRCin;
    }
```

When I try calculating 0,2,3 numbers in both functions I got different results:
for C function it is (DEC): 22017
for JAVA function it is (DEC): 28888

OK. I have converter C into Java code and got it partially working.

```
public static int CRC16_Test(byte[] data,  byte bytes) {
            int dataIndex = 0;
            short c;
            short [] crc= {0};

            crc[0] = (short)0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes); j++, dataIndex++) {
                c = (short)((Short.toUnsignedInt(crc[0]) >> 8 ^ Byte.toUnsignedInt(data[dataIndex])) << 8);
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if((Short.toUnsignedInt(c) & 0x8000) != 0) {
                        c = (short)(Short.toUnsignedInt(c) << 1 ^ 0x1021);
                    } else {
                        c = (short)(Short.toUnsignedInt(c) << 1);
                    }
                }
                crc[0] = (short)(Short.toUnsignedInt(c) ^ Short.toUnsignedInt(crc[0]) << 8);
            }
        return crc[0];
        }
```

It gives the same CRC values as C code for 0,2,3 numbers, but i.e. for numbers 255, 216, 228 C code crc is 60999 while JAVA crc is -4537.

OK. Finally thanks to your pointers I got this working.
The last change required was changing 'return crc[0]' to:

```
return (int) crc[0] & 0xffff;
```

... and it works...
Many thanks to all :)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? What did you find?

Comment: I use Eclipse for Java and it compiles fine... no issues

Comment: I'm not going to debug it for you. However, one thing sticks out -- I think you misunderstand the difference between signed and unsigned right shifts.

Comment: Also, "it compiles" means only that you got the syntax right... it says nothing about whether or not the code is correct.  You need to step through it in Eclipse, one line at a time, and watch what is happening to the variables.  You can then find where it deviates from your expectation.

Comment: if you refer to C function - it generates the CRC as device where it is connected... but OK, I will take a look at this. Thanks

Comment: You do a right shift on an `unsigned short` value in C.  Java does not have unsigned values (except `char` and it gets promoted in expressions). Consider what that means for right shifts.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694713/calculation-of-ccitt-standard-crc-with-polynomial-x16-x12-x5-1-in-java

Comment: OK. I have converted C code into Java. It works fine with number below 128... if I calculate crc16 for the values above 128 then I got a negative crc value... I update post with the JAVA code

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong. For a 16 bit value, –4537 is represented as the exact same 16 bits as 60999 is. If you would like for your routine to return the positive version, convert to `int` (which is 32 bits) and do an `& 0xffff`.

Comment: OK. I have changed last line to return (int) crc[0] & 0xffff; and it works fine now. Thanks!